# SQL: function trunc(timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to transform a date column to week by using the following code:

```
select trunc(join_date, 'D') as join_wk from my_table
```

But I got the following errors:

```
function trunc(timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

where `join_date` is of the format:

```
2017-08-24 14:49:59
```

What did I do wrong in the query? Thanks!

Comment: As the error says, that function doesn't exist. Maybe you were looking for [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-datetime.html#functions-datetime-trunc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the function is `date_trunc`, you have to swap the parameters:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('D', join_date) AS join_wk FROM my_table
```